# Convert String TimeStamp"2016-12-26 19:26:36.915" To Standard Timestamp format "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.sss"

Tags: java

I need to convert Convert `String TimeStamp"2016-12-26 19:26:36.915"` To Standard `Timestamp` format `"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.sss"` using core java.

Please help me out the standard way to code this.

Comment: Since it is an ISO format, with Java 8+, you can simply use `LocalDateTime.parse(input)`.

Answer (score -1):

```
    try{
    String inputTime = "2016-12-26 19:26:36.915";
    String date_format = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.sss";
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(date_format);

    //You will get a date object below from String you provide
    Date date = dateFormat.parse(inputTime);
    }catch(ParseException exception){
        System.out.println(exception.toString());
    }
```